# iPhone 6 - What can cause the front camera, rear camera and the flash to stop working, all at the same time?

Tags: iphone, repair

The front camera, rear camera and the flash light all stopped working simultaneously after I changed the charging port of my iPhone 6 myself (Apple doesn't do this).

I initially thought that the cable might not have been seated properly but that is not the case, I'm pretty sure.

Is there a way I can go about diagnosing this?

Edit:
I followed this video for changing the port - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnX_KKJnjOQ

The rest of the phone, including the new port, is working totally normally.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Well, there seems to be a connection between you replacing the Lightning port and this issue. Did you follow online instructions to do the replacement? Could you provide the link?

Comment: is the entire phone working properly except the camera? Has any of the components been swapped before?

Comment: No other components were swapped before. I followed this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnX_KKJnjOQ

The charging port is working like it should, not other issues with the phone whatsoever

Comment: It might be because Apple requires the phone to be verified through some mechanism (proprietary) if parts are changed. So people can't swap parts and sell old iPhone as new ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is a power supply chip responsible for powering both cameras if you removed the display you may have accidentally have damaged this small and delicate chip, without power to the cameras the flashlight will also not work. You can see the chip pointed out by a pair of tweezers in the picture below. it is normally covered in the black substance like the parts around it, I removed it in order to give a clearer view of the chip in question.
[image: iPhone 6 board (display connectors)]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check if this is indeed damaged. Looks like a strong possibility at the moment. Is this repairable if given to a decent technician?

Comment: Yes I've repaired many myself, it just might be a little difficult to find a technician that can do micro soldering. Best of luck getting your phone back together and working!